# how to remove new line after comma for array element in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm-2017.1

I am applying a **auto formatting (Code|Reformat Code ) in phpStrom** which adds a new line after the the comma of array elements. Here is sample of code before and after applying auto formatting.

**Before**

```
public function getResponse() {
    return [
        'venue_id' => '1234'
        ,'match_name' => 'One-Day'
        ,'team1_id' => '123'
        ,'team2_id' => '456'
    ];
}
```

**After**

```
public function getResponse() {
    return [
        'venue_id' => '1234'
        ,
        'match_name' => 'One-Day'
        ,
        'team1_id' => '123'
        ,
        'team2_id' => '456'
    ];
}
```

Adding a comma to new line before the element is the coding style. Please help me to remove the new line through auto formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a lot a, find the setting where we can change this feature. Go the **Setting|Editor|Code Style|PHP**

Open the third tab **Wrapping and Braces**  and you will find the array initializer property. Click in front of this property. And change this value to **chop down if long**. Here is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Phpstorm | Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Array Initializer change "Do not wrap" may help you